# Microsoft-Cognitive : Emotion API

Tags: python-3.x, api, azure-cognitive-services

I get the response below after making a call to the emotion api. How can i be able to have a variable that only gets the score for happiness only? I want something like data=happiness then i could be able to just print data.

```
{
    "FaceRectangle": {
      "Top": 141,
      "Left": 331,
      "Width": 52,
      "Height": 52
    },
    "Scores": {
      "Anger": 0.002451766,
      "Contempt": 0.0005512201,
      "Disgust": 0.0063303886,
      "Fear": 0.000122375583,
      "Happiness": 0.9589189,
      "Neutral": 0.0222537462,
      "Sadness": 0.008983561,
      "Surprise": 0.000388026354
    }
}
```

Here is the python code

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64, sys

headers = {
    # Request headers. Replace the placeholder key below with your subscription key.
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '**************************',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({


        })

body = open('clouds.jpg','rb').read()

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body, headers)

    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)

    conn.close()
```

except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)

Comment: `data['Scores']['Happiness']` (assuming you save the result in a variable named `data`)

Comment: I want something like data=happiness then i could be able to just print data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@falsetru is correct, but you should note that Emotion API

- Returns an array of faces, even if there's only one, and
- The field names will be camel-cased, unlike the snippet you've added

```py
import requests

body = {'url':'YOUR-IMAGE-URL'}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'YOUR-KEY'
}
req = requests.post('https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize', headers=headers, data=str(body))
faces = req.json()
for face in faces:
   print face['scores']['happiness']
```

Comment: I want something like data=happiness then i could be able to just print data

Comment: i still get this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What endpoint are you calling in to the API?  The error description sounds like you're getting very different results than what I'm expecting.

If you have an array of faces, and want to get an array of happiness scores, you'd do something like `map(lambda f: f['scores']['happiness'], faces)`

Comment: check the python code above i have just edited the question then tell me how i can create a variable to hold the score of happiness

Comment: `import json
faces = json.loads(data)
happiness = faces[0]['scores']['happiness'] if len(faces)>0 else 0`

Comment: I get this error>> IndentationError: unexpected indent at faces

Comment: I don't think you can add newlines in a comment.  I was hoping the line breaks was obvious.  It's `import json` followed by `faces = json.loads(data)` and then finally `happiness = faces[0]['scores']['happiness'] if len(faces)>0 else 0`.